# Missing form-action csp directive in CSPDirective

Tags: wicket

I don't see the CSP directive form-action in the CSPDirective enums in any of the wicket versions? Is it possible to update the api.
I am using wicket 9.15.0 version.

Comment: I just filled https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-7093. Hopefully someone will work on it for Wicket 9.17.  You can also send a Pull request at https://github.com/apache/wicket/pulls !